# Merging multiple Javascript objects into one. What does Stream.call(this) do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I'm studying the NodeJS Stream code and this example from this [Streams article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93):

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const inStream = new Readable({
  read() {}
});

inStream.push('ABCDEFGHIJKLM');
inStream.push('NOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

inStream.push(null); // No more data

inStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

When I step into the `new Readable()` call, I see code that looks like this:

```
const Stream = require('stream');

function Readable(options) {
   // ... 
   Stream.call(this);
}
```

**What does `Stream.call(this)` do?**  I haven't seen code like this before.

I know what the Javascript Object.call() method does and typically have seen it with another function.

```
myObj.myFunc.call(this);
```

I read the MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call and the example code combines two objects together.

**So my belief is that the `Readable` object after calling `Stream.call(this)` has all of the Stream functions and field values.**

**Is this correct?**

I'm guessing that this is the way Javascript did inheritance-like functionality, but without inheritance.  I think it's really equivalent to merging multiple Javascript objects.

So to prove my understanding, I wrote a [JSFiddle code example](https://jsfiddle.net/PatS2265/6u8hscx3/) which shows three functions fun1, fun2, and fun3 and has MyMultiObj call them as shown below:

```
function MyMultiObj() {
   fun1.call(this);
   fun2.call(this);
   fun3.call(this);
}

let myMulti = new MyMultiObj();
```

In this code the `myMulti` object has all the functionality and fields of the 4 functions MyMultiObj, fun1, fun2, and fun3.

I also noticed that functions defined via prototyping (e.g., `fun2.prototype.really2()` were not merged/available, which makes sense because this approach is NOT using prototyping).

I think this is pretty cool, and can see the benefits, but want to

- (a) verify that my understanding is correct, ... the `Readable` object after calling `Stream.call(this)` has all of the Stream functions and field values, and
- (b) find out why this is done instead of typical prototyping/inheritance (if there is a reason).

Comment: It’s calling the parent constructor. `Readable` inherits from `Stream`, so it sets its prototype to inherit from `Stream`’s prototype and makes this call to initialize itself. With ES6 classes, it’d look like `class Readable extends Stream { constructor() { super(); } }` (although you can omit a `constructor()` if it just calls `super()`).

Comment: @Ry, my belief is that it really isn't the parent constructor because it's not using ```class extends``` or ```Stream.prototype.func2```, is that correct.  I do agree that it is conceptually similar as you describe.  It's saying take this function and append it to myself (my ```this```).

Comment: No, it really is just regular inheritance, written in the most confusing possible way because the file abuses hoisting all over. Here’s where the prototype gets set: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/f01518edfd83e2235d84485d87621e61f675b4a7/lib/_stream_readable.js#L47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `call()` just executes a function with `this` being the object passed to it, inside of a constructor it is like a `super()` call in other languages (and ES6):

```
 function Stream() {
   this.something = 1;
 }

 function Readable () {
   Stream.call(this);
 }

 (new Readable()).something // 1
```

Equals:

```
 class Stream {
  constructor() {
     this.something = 1;
 }
}

class Stream extends Readable {
 constructor() {
  super(); // <<
 }
}
```

> So my belief is that the Readable object after calling Stream.call(this) has all of the Stream functions and field values.

Only the ones set directly in the constructor. It does not have values/methods of the prototype

Comment: My belief is that it _similar to_ inheritance but not really the same because it really is merging multiple objects into one.  Do you agree with me?

Comment: @pats yup kind of, although there is only one object.

Comment: Yes.  I should have said, one object takes on the capabilities (functions with fields) that the other functions add to it.  Conceptually, if each function fun1, fun2, fun3 represent constructors for three kinds of objects, then ```fun1.call(this)``` makes the current object now have the capabilities that the ```fun1()``` constructor adds.